# Wrong color being assigned to layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

My app requests some JSON data from my site's API from within my fragment's `onCreateView()` method:

```
apiService.getJson(5, new Callback<PostData>() {

    @Override
    public void success(PostData postData, Response response) {
        final PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postArray);
        postArray.addAll(postData.getData());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        retrofitError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

My adapter's `getView()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    Post post = getItem(position);

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        return view;
    }

    LayerDrawable shapeLayout = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.post_bg);
    GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) shapeLayout.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.post_bg_border);
    shape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#" + post.getColor()));

    return view;
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/post_bg_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, it's assigning the color to the next post, rather than the current one. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

the else branch is wrong, and you should remove it. converView is null just once. In your case after you assigned the color, the first time `(convertView == null)`, in the else branch, you are returning the same view over and over.

```
if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
}

LayerDrawable shapeLayout = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.link_info_bg);
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) shapeLayout.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.link_info_bg_border);
shape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#" + post.getColor()));
```

without `else`, is what you want

Comment: Forgot to remove that from some previous testing, but now the color isn't changing at all. It just stays black (the color I have set there by default). :/

Comment: Correction, it's setting the first color used on every post.